Problem with Bluetooth device
My Bluetooth works to pair my Redmi buds 5 pro, but the problem is that this device is not recognized as a output audio device, so it's not listed in the output devices, I tried a lot of things to solve it, but it didn't make a difference. I installed a blueman to see if it could solve it, and it just showed me that my device was not a headphone or something that could be used as audio output.


Sound and bluetooth are a nightmare combination on linux.  But you can try this in the terminal:
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
pactl list | grep -i bluetooth
pulseaudio --k
pulseaudio --start
